# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un input al hacer click a un checkbox generado dinámicamente?

Tags: php, javascript

Soy un aprendiz y he intentado durante 3 días resolver este problema y no puedo.
Genero una tabla dinámica con php, tanto los checkbox como el input text. Pero quiero poder marcar una checkbox y aparecerá automáticamente 1 en el input text de entrada.
Si alguien me puede ayudar, porque el método que uso, si marco id con el valor (document.getElementById('qtd').value = "1";), el resultado aparece solo en la primera fila, como se muestra en el código.

```js
function comprobar(obj) {
  if (obj.checked) {
    document.getElementById("qtd").value = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("qtd").value = "0";
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
<td class="wabi"><?php echo $row['prd_nome'];?><p style="font-size: 11px"><?php echo $row['descricao'];?></p>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['prd_id'];?>" name="<?php echo $row['prd_id'];?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $row['prd_id'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /></label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

[image: código js]

---

[image: código html]

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda que pusieras tu código en forma de texto y no en imágenes, de esa forma es mas fácil que puedan analizar tu código.

Comment: Ahora amigo, ya escribo

Comment: Cuando tu código se ejecuta, una vez que ya se procesa la conexión a SQL, si existe un elemento dentro del DOM que tenga el ID "qtd" ?

Comment: no, el id es para obture o valor del checkbox cuando esta marcado (ejemplo=1)

Comment: Te funciono alguna de las soluciones que te compartí?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora soy uno más que seguiré aprendiendo y también contribuiré a esta gran comunidad. Muchas gracias Jesus Ochoa, funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Perfecto, te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta y que votes esta misma para que pueda ayudar a más personas con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen distintas formas de resolver tu problemática, te comparto dos posibles caminos que puedes utilizar para solucionar esto.

Partiendo que en tu código php ya estas incluyendo la propiedad "id" del elemento igual a "name", a esta misma propiedad puedes concatenar el id del row que se esta generando, esto de la siguiente manera:

```
<td><input type="text" id="name<?php echo $row['prd_id'];?>"/></td>
```

A su vez tienes que modificar el código JS para que al momento de obtener los elementos dentro del DOM lo haga correctamente.

```
function comprobar(target) {
  var textInput = document.getElementById("name" + target.id);
  if (target.checked) {
    textInput.value = "1";
  } else {
    textInput.value = "0";
  }
}
```

En la siguiente liga puedes ver el funcionamiento de este código: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jerod8a/pen/RwaRbYg?editors=1010)

Si lo que buscas es no modificar tu código php puedes utilizar la funcion "closest" de javascript para encontrar el elemento mas cercano de tipo "tr", una vez que tengas el elemento "tr" puedes buscar el input de texto que anteriormente le agregaste su "id" igual a "name". el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function comprobar(target) {
  var textInput = target.closest('tr').getElementById('name');
  if (target.checked) {
    textInput.value = "1";
  } else {
    textInput.value = "0";
  }
}
```

En este segundo camino cabe mencionar que estamos utilizando una función que no es compatible con todos los navegadores.

A su vez tambien me gustaria comentarte que tengas mas cuidado al utilizar la propiedad "id" en los elemento HTML, esto debido a que es una propiedad que no se debe repetir dentro del DOM.

Para mas información de la propiedad "id" puedes revisar la siguiente liga: [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: Es solo una curiosidad, sé que es un desafío. Pero, ¿hay alguna forma de crear código compatible con todos los navegadores?

Comment: Si existen distintas formas de crear código compatible para todos los navegadores, la forma más utilizada es hacer uso de herramientas como webpack con Babel para transpirar tu código de JS de versiones modernas a antiguas.

Comment: Gracias, estudiaré un poco más al respecto, ahora me toca a mí dedicarme a aprender más. Muchas gracias por su contribución. Ya he votado y marcado las respuestas, pero como todavía soy nuevo, creo que todavía no es visible para todos, pero dice que cuenta. Saludos